# Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation

Tags: c++, matlab, dllexport

The project structure is: dynamic library project.
I try to generate a DLL.file based on a completed C++ project, and expect to compile it in MATLAB. After the Rebuid solution, the output reminds me 'Previous IPDB not found, fall back to full compilation.' and 'All 51 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found'.

Following the tutorials from others, I change the 'Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG:incremental)' to 'Use Fast Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)'. although the errors are solved in the output, I still cannot find any functions when I loadlibrary the generated dll.file. Besides, .lib and .exp are not found in the folder.

As a checking, the .cpp and .h files are added in an application project, and it works well.